# Queued jobs disappear after redis restarts

Tags: node.js, kue

When I put some jobs to `kue` and then I restart `redis` then queued jobs disappear. I assume that this is normal behavior but I was wondering if there is a way to keep queued jobs after `redis` restart? My app requires to have all jobs processed so I need one function/method to add job to queue that will guarantee that job is actually added to the queue and it will remain there until processed...

So is there any mechanism for this in`kue` or maybe in other `job queueing library` for node? Or I have to handle it on my own by storng each job in DB and then add jobs from db to kue?

Answer (score 1):

"Redis is an in-memory but persistent on disk database". It should be surviving restarts with your kue intact (mine does).

Comment: Well - I put job to queue - in `kue` UI I can see it is queued. When I restart redis and refresh `kue` UI there are no queued jobs. And when I start my worker it also does not get any jobs. But in `kue` UI I can see all completed jobs - so only queued jobs are missing. And without `redis` restart it works... Maybe it's something with my redis? I have redis on windows installed and I just run `redis-server.exe`...

Comment: Yes, I would ask a new question with tag redis and redis wihdows about why persistence isn't working. I'm pretty sure your issue isn't kue.

Comment: @user606521 did you solve this mate?  I am using Windows 10 and Redis-x64-3.2.100 and having the same problem.